# How to set the focus on text (no form)

Tags: html, focus, usability

I know about HTML5's `autofocus` attribute, but AFAIK it only applies to `input` tags.

Is there a way to set the focus automatically (and preferably without JS) on, say, a scrollable div with text, so that the viewer can immediately scroll using keyboard ?  Or would it be browser-specific ?

I can't find useful ressources online so I'm wondering if "focus" if the right word.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div tabindex='0'> 
      this will receive the focus immediately
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `tabindex`, but it doesn't seem to work (at least with Firefox 37.0.2), and this answer contradicts R4nc1d's one…

Answer (score 1):

```
tabindex="0"
```

The tabindex value can allow for some interesting behaviour.

1. If given a value of "-1", the element can't be tabbed to but focus
   can be given to the element programmatically (using element.focus()).
2. If given a value of 0, the element can be focused via the keyboard
   and falls into the tabbing flow of the document.
3. Values greater than 0 create a priority level with 1 being the most
   important.

For more info you can look at the following link http://snook.ca/archives/accessibility_and_usability/elements_focusable_with_tabindex

***UPDATE***

The other option is to try something like this.
Add the following code to the body tag, substituting the form and field names for your own:

```
<body OnLoad="document.myform.mytextfield.focus();">

<form name="myform">
   <input type="text" name="mytextfield">
   <button type="button" onclick="javascript:alert('testing')" name="myButton">Click Me!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: According to point 2 setting `tabindex` to 0 won't help.  Setting it to 1 makes it accessible by only one tab pressure, which is already a great step forward, but not focused by default.